# Camel blueprint sql transaction manager

Tags: java, mysql, transactions, apache-camel

I got two inserts which I want to have under transactional control. If one of them fails the other one also shall not be executed/inserted. This works fine when doing it right in the MySQL like this

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO table (field) VALUES (value);
INSERT INTO table2 (field) VALUES (value);
COMMIT;
```

Now using camel I already tried

```
<to uri="sql:START TRANSACTION; INSERT INTO table (field) VALUES (value);INSERT INTO table2 (field) VALUES (value);COMMIT;"/>
```

which produces an sql syntax error.
The second thing I tried is

```
<to uri="sql:START TRANSACTION"/>
<to uri="sql:INSERT INTO table (field) VALUES (value)"/>
<to uri="sql:INSERT INTO table2 (field) VALUES (value)"/>
<to uri="sql:COMMIT"/>
```

which works but if one insert fails the other one is still being executed and inserted.

I also found this
http://camel.apache.org/transactional-client.html but I am using blueprint and these examples only seem to be for spring. So if anyone got a good example doing it with camel blueprint this would be great.

Can anyone help me to do this in camel?

Comment: How does that even work? I mean your uri is just a SQL statement. There is no component associated with it. Could you perhaps post your entire route i.e. Blueprint.xml.

Comment: Oh sry forgot the "sql:" - added it now

Comment: ich danke Ihnen , dass eine Menge helfen if I remember my Deutsch correctly.

Comment: One last thing you mention a syntax error could you post the error as well. Any clue will help.

Answer (score 1):

What about using a TX manager? 
Define an XA JDBC resource and use it with your calls , something like here https://github.com/tmielke/fuse-demos/blob/master/Camel/Camel-JMS-JDBC-XA-TX/routing/src/main/resources/OSGI-INF/blueprint/camel-context.xml

G.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the "Engine" is InnoDB (not MyISAM).  MyISAM silently ignores transaction statements (`START`, `COMMIT`).

Use the mysql commandline tool, and do `SHOW CREATE TABLE ...`.  At the end of the table it will specify the Engine.